# ng-pattern Validation not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to do validation with angular and Bootstrap but for some reasons ng-pattern validation is not working in Zip Code. Any help will be great in this.

Here's [**FIDDLE LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/UGLjh/65/)

Not able to paste full code, but here is how I am attempting to use the `ng-pattern` directive:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="zipCode" name="zipCode"
       ng-model="auth.zip" ng-pattern="^(\d{5}-\d{4}|\d{5})$" required="">
```

Comment: The CSS is not relevant to your question. But the regular expression you use in `ng-pattern` might be ;)

Comment: i know css is not relevant. Stack over flow was asking for some code so just pasted something.

Comment: stack overflow is asking you to provide some of the code from the fiddle link.  So, that this question makes sense in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that when you place the pattern inline instead of a scope variable it expects `/` around the regex, like a litteral.

Like this:

```
/^(\d{5}-\d{4}|\d{5})$/
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UGLjh/66/)**

See the **[input docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input)**, check out the arguments section then ngPattern

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use like this

```
$scope.zipNumbr = /^[0-9]{1,6}$/;
```